# Сортировка дерева

Tags: sqlite

Есть вот такая таблица, представляющая собой древовидное оглавление:

```
CREATE TABLE "tree" (
  "Id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
  "Parent"  INTEGER,
  "SortKey"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Id" UNIQUE ("Id")
);

INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (1, 'Текст1'  , null, 1);
INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (2, 'Текст2'  , null, 0);
INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (3, 'Текст3'  , null, 1);
INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (4, 'Текст1.1', 1   , 2);
INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (5, 'Текст1.2', 1   , 1);
INSERT INTO "tree" VALUES (6, 'Текст3.1', 3   , 0);
```

Где поле `Parent` - ссылка на "родительскую" запись. Если оно `NULL`, значит запись в корне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким запросом можно это оглавление вывести в отсортированном виде.

**Вариант 1**

Упорядочивание в смежных записях ("потомках" одного "родителя") идет по полю `Name`:

```
1, 'Текст1'  , null, 1
4, 'Текст1.1', 1   , 2
5, 'Текст1.2', 1   , 1
2, 'Текст2'  , null, 0
3, 'Текст3'  , null, 1
6, 'Текст3.1', 3   , 0
```

**Вариант 2**

Упорядочивание в смежных записях ("потомках" одного "родителя") идет по полю `SortKey`:

```
2, 'Текст2'  , null, 0
1, 'Текст1'  , null, 1
5, 'Текст1.2', 1   , 1
4, 'Текст1.1', 1   , 2
3, 'Текст3'  , null, 1
6, 'Текст3.1', 3   , 0
```

Понимаю, что запросы по факту должны быть идентичны - разница только по полю сортировки. Привел уж для полноты.

Comment: А уровень вложенности какой ?

Comment: Интересный вопрос) Желательно без ограничений, в разумных пределах. Ну пусть будет 1к.

Comment: Упс ... правильное замечание! Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам потребуется собрать "путь" по дереву до каждого листа и отсортировать по нему. Так как путь текстовое поле, числовой ключ сортировки надо будет дополнить нулями слева для правильной сортировки. Для текстового ключа сортировки этого не требуется. Так как ключ сортировки у вас не уникален, пришлось добавить еще и сортировку по id в пределах одного sortKey, иначе ветви выстраиваются не верно.

Для сортировки по SortKey запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
with recursive Q(id, name, parent,path) as(
  select id, name, parent,
          substr('0000000000' || SortKey, -10, 10)||substr('0000000000' || id, -10, 10)
    from tree where Parent is null
  union all
  select T.id, T.name, T.parent,
         path||'/'||substr('0000000000' || T.SortKey, -10, 10)||substr('0000000000' || T.id, -10, 10)
    from Q, tree T
   where T.parent=Q.id
)
 select * from Q order by path
```

Для сортировки по имени всю сборку из `substr()` заменить на поле `name`. При наличии одинаковых `name` на одном уровне сортировки придется так же, как и в примере выше добавлять id записи.

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/350f6/5)

Comment: Как я понимаю, если глубина будет большой - получатся огромные пути?

Comment: @Majestio Да, правильно понимаете. есть смысл для числовых полей короче сделать дополнение, если таких больших чисел не бывает

Comment: И тем не менее, огромное спасибо!)

Comment: А почему бы просто не использовать обход дерева в глубину, тогда `Q` сразу вернёт записи в нужном порядке? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/350f6/6

Comment: @PetSerAl Да, это заметно проще. Я не знал, что некоторые СУБД поддерживают order by в рекурсивной части